# UIToolbar not resizing when rotating with autolayout, with UIBarButtonItems misplaced

Tags: objective-c, rotation, height, autolayout, uitoolbar

it's the first time I'm seriously using autolayout so I'm sure I'm missing something obvious.

I have a very simple view embedded in a UINavigationController. There are three subviews: a UIWebView, a UIToolbar (which in turn contains three UIBarButtons) and a UIActivityIndicatorView. It's just a basic browser view, basically.

I managed to have everything appear as it should even on rotation, except for the toolbar: if the view is first loaded in vertical orientation, going landscape will not resize the toolbar from 44 to 32 points. Originally, before I wiped everything out, it did resize the toolbar BUT the built-in UIBarButtonItems appeared lower and cut off, as if the toolbar was still 44 points tall but pushed 16 points out of the screen.
If the view is first loaded horizonttaly, the bar is 32 points high but the built-in UIBarButtonItems appear still like that, and rotating to vertical will keep it at 32 points.

[image: example]

I honestly have no idea how to make this work as expected (ie. resize properly when rotated, with the buttons showing properly!), so if anyone could point me in the right direction -- pun intended -- I would be really grateful.

The activity indicator is right in the middle of the frame, with these constraints:

- Align Center X to Superview
- Align Center Y to Superview

The web view is set to use all available space from the top of the view (including the navbar) up to the top of the toolbar, and has these contraints:

- Top Space to Superview
- Bottom Space to Toolbar
- Align Trailing to Toolbar
- Bottom Space to Toolbar (it's actually listed twice)
- Align Leading to Toolbar

The toolbar is a mess. It has:

- Bottom space to Superview
- Align Center X to Superview
- Top Space to Web View
- Align Trailing to Web View
- Top Space to Web View (listed twice)
- Leading Space to Superview
- Align Leading to Web View
- Bottom Space to Bottom Layout Guide

The problem is that by not adding any constraints at all, the web view is much bigger than it should be, and the toolbar doesn't even show.
I mostly set these constraints using the horizontal and vertical red bars (similar to springs and strouts) in the 'pin' popover for autolayout, but I'm starting to think that's not the most appropriate approach.

Note that I'm not trying to use autolayout *within* the toolbar, I read that it wouldn't work and I'm just using the built-in buttons plus a couple of labelled ones (those 'arrows' are really unicode characters, I may change them to prettier images at some point.)

Thank you in advance. :-)

Comment: Sorry, may be I didn't get it. Do you really want to change the toolbar's height to 32px in horizontal orientation or are you doing it as a compromise to keep it on screen or to prevent it from hiding from the webview?

Comment: By default the toolbar is 44 points high when in portrait orientation and 32 points high when in landscape orientation, you can see this in the Mail app. For some reason, in my app either it does not change or it changes but the buttons within are misplaced (as if it were just pushed down, partially out of bounds). I'm sure it's related to the constraints, but I'm not sure how else to set them so that views are correctly laid out AND the toolbar's buttons aren't cut off as shown in the screenshot.

Comment: Try keeping exactly these constraints for the webview : make (top space, leading space and trailing space to superview) = 0(or the constant that you want). bottom space to toolbar = 0

Comment: Alas it doesn't help: if the view opens in portrait, everything is ok though in landscape it stays big, but that's a minor problem. The big issue is that when the view opens in landscape, the button appears like in the screenshot above. I think it's really something related to the autolayout constraints of the toolbar, more than the webview, since it's the toolbar that doesn't handle the layout correctly.

Comment: It looks like iAd's canDisplayBannerAds on the view also has something to do with it, because *without* it the icons aren't misplaced, though the bar stays with whatever size it had when the view first appeared (tall if portrait, short if landscape) even when rotated.